# Carregar um GridView com registros selecionados

Tags: c#, asp.net, webforms

Como carregar um GridView no WebForm com algumas linhas já selecionadas ?

Estou tentando o seguinte código porém sem sucesso...

```
protected void BindGridAcesso(int idSenha)
        {
            Usuario usuario = IdentificadorUsuario.ObterDadosUsuario();

            var lstUsuarios = new EntidadeNegocio().ListarExcetoUsuarioLogado(usuario.UsuarioId);

            if (idSenha != 0)
            {

                var lstUsuarioSenha = new EntidadeNegocio().ListarPorSenha(idSenha);

                gdvAcesso.DataSource = lstUsuarios;
                gdvAcesso.DataBind();

                int linhasGrid = gdvAcesso.Rows.Count;

                foreach (var item in lstUsuarioSenha)
                {
                    foreach (GridViewRow gvr in gdvAcesso.Rows)
                    {
                        if (gvr.Cells[1].Text == item.NomeUsuario)
                        {
                            gvr.RowState = DataControlRowState.Selected;
                        }
                    }

                }

            }

        }
```

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: Não entendi essa sua linha selecionada, seria colorida ou algo do tipo?

Comment: editei o post com a imagem...seria com o checkbox da linha selecionado

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use o Evento [RowDataBound](https://msdn.microsoft.com/pt-br/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.gridview.rowdatabound(v=vs.110).aspx) da *Grid*, ele permite uma configuração linha a linha.

Basta você obter seu Checkbox e marcá-lo.

Meu exemplo ficou assim:

```
protected void NomedoGridView_RowDataBound(object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e)
{
      if (e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.DataRow)
      {
         CheckBox chkSelect = (CheckBox)e.Row.FindControl("idCheckBox");
         chkSelect.checked = true;   

      }
}
```

Comment: opa valeu deu certinho aqui !

Comment: @Daniel que bom que pude te ajudar.